# Data structure for React weekly scheduler

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a weekly scheduler for workers that resembles google calendar using React. I am quite new to React and CSS so I am not sure as to what is the best data structure that represents the scheduler, that will enable the user to click on a section and it will open a form with that section details such as day, start-time and end-time. I have watched [Traversy Media React JS Crash Course 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8) which was very helpful but I am still unsure about a good data structure that will give me the functionality of a calendar such as google's.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Where is the data going to be stored? In a external database? IndexedDB? local storage?

Comment: Well, what data does your scheduler need to hold?

Comment: I understand that my question wasn't clear, I meant to ask how to structure the week sheet in order that the new shift will be displayed in the correct day and time region?